# nginx load balancer not spreading the requests to all servers. only on 2

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have 10 servers configured in the `nginx` lb, only 2 are getting requests...

```
events { worker_connections 1024;}

http {
    upstream app {
        #least_conn;
        server test_1:3500;
        server test_2:3500;
        server test_3:3500;
        server test_4:3500;
        server test_5:3500;
        server test_6:3500;
        server test_7:3500;
        server test_8:3500;
        server test_9:3500;
        server test_10:3500;
    }

    server {
        listen 3600;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app;
        }
    }
}
```

Servers `server test_5:3500;` and `server test_8:3500;` are getting all the requests... why?
The load I'm testing is 800 requests over 30 seconds to server `localhost:3600`.

it has the same behavior with `least_conn;`
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the host file from your load balancer instance?

Comment: @Hackerman localhost:3600